# How to append checkboxes from 2 different tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBPB6/31/) there are two tables which are having checkboxes in each row.

When the `To` button is clicked then a dialog box appears and after selecting user or groups drop down menu the respective tables appear.Now if the checkboxes are selected then the names corresponding to the checkboxes appear at the bottom.

For example from the groups dropdown if i select the 1st check box then `alltest` will appear at bottom.And similarily if i select the 1st checkbox then `test` will appear at the bottom.

**My problem** Suppose I selected 1st 2 checkboxes from the users drop down then `test test2` will be shown at the bottom.Now if I selected the groups dropdown and select the 1st checkbox then `test test2` is disappearing and `alltest` is appearing.I want `test test2 alltest` all in the bottom.That means all the selected checkboxes name at the bottom.Please tell me how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/rynhe/LBPB6/33/

```
function appendtext() {
        var httext = "";
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked", "#mytable12").each(function() {
          httext += $(this).parent().next().text() + " ,";   
       });
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked", "#groupsTable1").each(function() {
          httext += $(this).parent().next().text() + " ,";          
        });
        return httext;
}
     $("input[type='checkbox']", "#mytable12").on('change', function (event) {
      $("#ToAdd").html(appendtext());
   });

$("input[type='checkbox']", "#groupsTable1").on('change', function (event) {
         $("#ToAdd").html(appendtext()); 
   });

});
```

While clicking,You have to check all `checkboxes` in `user` and `group`...

```
$('#ToOk').click(function(){
   $("#number").val($("#ToAdd").text());
});
```

Get all values from span `ToAdd` and add that value to `number` textbox

Answer (score 0):

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/Zh8kB/3/
Try as shown below
Use separate  tag

```
<span id="ToAdd_info">i want the checked boxes name here</span>
<span id="ToAdd"></span>
```

and modified your js as shown below
var count=0;var TosCheckbox = new Array();

```
     $("input[type='checkbox']", "#mytable12").on('change', function (event) {
alert('hi');
        $("#ToAdd_info").hide();
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked", "#mytable12").each(function() {
          //  alert('hi');
           $("#ToAdd").append($(this).parent().next().text() + " ");           
       });
   });

$("input[type='checkbox']", "#groupsTable1").on('change', function (event) {
alert('hello');
        $("#ToAdd_info").hide();
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked", "#groupsTable1").each(function() {
          //  alert('hi');
           $("#ToAdd").append($(this).parent().next().text() + " ,");           
       });
   });

});


$('body').on('click', '#to-btn', function () {
   console.log($('a[href="#users"]'));
   $("#ToAdd_info").show(); 
    $("#ToAdd").html('');
 $('a[href="#users"]').trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the output is coming like this `alltest ,alltest ,fff `